# How can I add custom button on Inline Django Admin fields?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have main django admin class that includes inline class with two fields pos_x and pos_y.

I want to update this fields via JS and modal-window.

Can I add button in InlineClass without changing any admin html?

```
class InlineClass(CommonInlineConfigurationMixin):
  model = MapPoint
  fields = ['title', ('pos_x', 'pos_y')]
  form = Form
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you can do it like this:

```
class InlineClass(CommonInlineConfigurationMixin):
    model = MapPoint
    fields = ['title', ('pos_x', 'pos_y'), 'button']
    readonly_fields = ("button",)
    form = Form
    class Media:
        js = ("js/my_code.js",)

    def button (self, obj):
      return "<button type='button' onclick='my_code()'>Click Me!</button>"

    button.allow_tags=True
```

And put the my_code.js into your "static/js" folder.

Comment: "Unknown field(s) (button) specified for MapPoint"

Comment: You also have to add the button field to the readonly fields - see edit. Then the admin will know where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ger.s.brett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3091263/ger-s-brett) answer i have to format html in return, like this:

```
def button (self, obj):
   return format_html("<button type='button' onclick='my_code()'>Click Me!</button>")
```